# Opposite method of startsWith() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know what startsWith() does in js.
Is there a method that checks opposite of what startsWith() does?? Something like "notstartsWith()".
I want a method that would return false if a string starts with a pattern and true if it doesn't.

Comment: `!x.startsWith(y)`

Comment: why not test [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT)?

Answer (score 9):

Use `startsWith` with the string you want to check against, then invert the check with `!`:

```
if (!str.startsWith('foo')) {
  // string does not start with foo
}
```

Comment: i know the use of logical not and i used it in my code. Just for knowlegde i asked the question.